# Copy and Filter Array (Extract Array Element) using Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB 3.2

I have a single document with an embedded Array, for which I'd like to extract a single element and keep the rest of the whole document.

My document:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  items: [
    {
      type: "A",
      id: 41
    },
    {
      type: "A",
      id: 42
    },
    {
      type: "B",
      id: 43
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now I'd like to have some query that does the following things:

1. Find document with `_id=1`
2. Take the `items` array, find all elements with `type=A AND id=42`. Then put those elements within the `machtingItems` array.
3. Slice the `items` array, so it contains max. 2 elements

The result should be this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  items: [
    {
      type: "A",
      id: 41
    },
    {
      type: "A",
      id: 42
    }
  ],
  matchingItems: [
    {
      type: "A",
      id: 42
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically there should always be only a single element matching `type=A and id=42`, but after looking at the Aggregation Framework it might be easier to just use an Array for `matchingItems` instead of a simple field.

I know how to `$match` the whole document and how to `$slice` the array. But I just can't figure out how to extract a single element from the array and place it inside another field. (Step 2)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aggregation basically not to be used for changing documents, it is reporting feature. If every document always have at least one `type=A and id=42` i would rather write the mongo shell script with forEach and changind docs.

Comment: If your question is about extracting elements and placing it to another field you may look at `$unwind` and `$push`/`$addToSet` respectively.